# invoke vs map in Mutinity java reactive code

Tags: quarkus, java-11, reactive, quarkus-reactive

i not understand why the code:

```
 Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).onItem().invoke(
            x -> return "example"
        ).subscribe().with(System.out::println);
```

-> print: 1,2,3,.. (every 10 sec)

not produce the same output like this:

```
Multi.createFrom().ticks().every(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).map(
            x -> return "example"
        ).subscribe().with(System.out::println);
```

-> print  example,example .. (every 10 sec)

why?
It's a quarkus project with
dependecy:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `invoke` method is called when an item (or failure if used after `onFailure()`) arrives but does not send its result downstream. It's just to peek at the event, not to change it.

The `map` method is called when an item arrives and transforms that event. The result of the method is sent downstream.

References:

- `map`: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/tutorials/transforming-items/
- `invoke`: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/tutorials/observing-events